# How to get all rows with using WHERE using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for something, which can select all rows in db using WHERE like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fb_post WHERE fb_page_id = 17 AND YEAR(date) = ALL ORDER BY date
```

So, In my app, I set date from local variable.

```
SELECT * FROM fb_post WHERE fb_page_id = 17 AND YEAR(date) = ? ORDER BY date
```

In some case, I want to select all years, is there any key word for select all? I don't want to write second query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fb_post WHERE fb_page_id = 17 ORDER BY date
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Make separate queries, one with the year and one without.

Comment: `where (YEAR(date) = :p or :p is null)`

Answer (score 0):

If you send parameter null in order to get all, the below code will help you on mysql. For Mssql replace IFNULL with ISNULL and NVL for Oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM fb_post WHERE fb_page_id = 17 AND YEAR(date) = IFNULL('your param here',YEAR(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean that conditions the date check:

```
SELECT * FROM fb_post
WHERE fb_page_id = 17 AND (NOT checkDate OR YEAR(date) = ALL)
ORDER BY date
```

If you set checkDate to false, `YEAR(date) = ALL` will be ignored.